# Using id of HREF to position dynamic data in a TD given diff. pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a non-hackish way to append to or use some elem (noted by an id) and append to it but after it before a block element. Not sure how to explain this.

I have various pages. And I have to insert some data (that is generated via ajax). Now, this data is retrieved after the page is loaded and as such, I have to inject some content - but because the pages are different (I want to use a plugin so I can just drop it into these pages and boom - dynamic content is placed appropriately).

** EDIT ::: If there is text after the HREF, my *inserted* items must be after it (and subsequent br tag). I was thinking that perhaps I insert after the href up to the last block element (div) or if not, then bottom of the div (noted in last example).

for some pages, the layout is like this..

```
<td>
  <div>
     <a href="someurl" id="uniqueIDhere">monsters</a>  come see this show!!<br>
     // span with content injected here
  </div>
```

or

```
<td>
  <div>
     <a href="someurl" id="uniqueIDhere">monsters</a>
     // span with content injected here
  </div>
```

or

```
 <td>
     <a href="someurl" id="uniqueIDhere">monsters</a>
     // span with content injected here
 </td>
```

or

```
<td>
  <div>
    <span>
     <a href="someurl" id="uniqueIDhere">monsters</a> yo you yo yo yo<br>
    </span>
     // span with content injected here
  </div>
```

So, that href could be wrapped in a DIV or a SPAN or not.. but its always in a TD.. 
So, basically I want to inject my "new dynamic" data within the last div of the TD or if there is none, just at the end of the td (but still in it).

any ideas? I figure to use the href ID (should use this as there are a few links i Have to do this to), get the parent TD and then append to it in some fashion?

Comment: Inserting content after an element can be done with [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/), but suddenly in the last example you break the pattern, and then you say it could be inside a div or a span, but for some reason now it's suddenly suppose to be inserted after the span but not the div, so there really is no common pattern?

Comment: well, I have to work with the HTML that already exists. My thought was insert after within the last block element. Not sure that can work. I don't know if after() will work, because I have to insert it not only after the HREF, but any text following it and that <br>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for the jQuery [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method:

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the
>   set of matched elements.

```
$("#uniqueIDhere").after("<div>INSERT WHATEVER HERE</div>")
```

**EDIT**:

After reading this question again, I think you may be looking for [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
$("div").has("#uniqueIDhere").append("<div>INSERT WHATEVER HERE</div>")​
```

Here we use [`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) to filter the list of `div` elements that do not contain `uniqueIDhere` and then use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add the text, html, etc.. to the end of the `div`.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hLFmS/4/)**

Comment: @jamesemanon - Let me know if it doesn't and I'll look into another solution, but based on what you're trying to accomplish I think this will work =)

Comment: Hey - I came across an issue, otherwise it works real well. The appending happens on all divs that contain this uniqueHref.. so, its showing up in numerous places... is there a way to stipulate the div that has the href and not others? so, if we have nested divs, it will append to all of them. -- actually I think *closest()* will work.

Comment: I was under the impression that `#uniqueIDhere` was a unique id. So if you're experiencing something of that sort then you have multiple elements with the same id (which should not happen)

Comment: well, any particular uniqueID will be uniq ue.. BUT there are numerous Divs that surround it. SO, the appending was happening in numerous places. I ended up using ".closest()" and it sorted things out. Thanks again for your answer. It works great.

Comment: `closest` should work, or you can also use `parent` and give a selector. Without seeing the complete markup I had no idea, but it seems like you've got it figured out =)